# Using bulma-extensions in rails 6

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, bulma, webpacker

I have a rails 6 app running with the bulma framework.

Bulma was installed with yarn and imported with app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

Works fine!

I installed bulma-extensions with yarn and have tried different things to no avail...

importing as per documentation:

```
@import 'bulma/bulma';
@import '~bulma-extensions/bulma-switch';
```

or

```
@import 'bulma/bulma';
@import '~bulma-switch';
```

both give a hard error from rails:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bulma-switch.
    on line 3:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
>> @import '~bulma-switch';
```

I tried:

```
@import 'bulma/bulma';
@import 'node_modules/bulma-extensions/bulma-switch/dist/css/bulma-switch.min.css';
```

Which does not give any rails errors but it also does not render the switch - just a normal checkbox. In the browser console i get this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/node_modules/bulma-extensions/bulma-switch/dist/css/bulma-switch.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I have noticed that bulma and bulma-extensions are distributed very differently:

Bulma:

```
root@ca17f2b6250d:/myapp/node_modules# ls bulma -al
total 68
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root   288 Nov  2 21:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 777 root root 24864 Dec 15 15:40 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 43808 Nov  2 21:35 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1080 Nov  2 21:35 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 11138 Nov  2 21:35 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   300 Nov  2 21:35 bulma.sass
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root   256 Nov  2 21:36 css
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1761 Nov  2 21:35 package.json
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root   352 Nov  2 21:36 sass
```

Bulma-extensions/bulma-switch:

```
root@ca17f2b6250d:/myapp/node_modules# ls bulma-extensions/bulma-switch/ -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  256 Dec 15 15:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root  832 Dec 15 15:36 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6148 Dec 15 15:40 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3608 Dec 13 15:26 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1063 Dec 13 15:26 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  616 Dec 13 15:26 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  128 Dec 15 15:36 dist
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  128 Dec 15 15:39 src
```

I have to admit that I don't get what webpack does here.
Why can't it find the minified css? why is it trying to serve it directly from the bulma css file and not compile it into the general css pack?

Answer (score 1):

When you install bulma with `yarn` you need to use webpacker to import it, not the asset pipeline. So:

*app/javascript/packs/application.scss*

```scss
@import '~bulma';
@import '~bulma-switch';
```

The tilde (~) tells webpacker to search for the package in *node_modules*.

Then you tell your layout to include this pack:

*app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```